# Realtek rtl8188fu Wifi adapters are too slow

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have an rtl8188fu wifi adapter and I have installed driver for it from https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu . My problem is that the network speed is too slow. I have tried the wifi adapter on another Windows computer and it was fast. But when I use it on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop, it is very slow. It hardly reaches 3 Kilobits per second. With this I came to know that the problem was not with the adapter itself, but with the driver or the Operating System.

I have tested it with [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=speed+test), https://speedtest.net, speedtest cli, fast.com, etc. It's really weird that it reaches more than 50 Kilobits per second on windows while it cannot get more than 3 Kilobits per second on Ubuntu. Help me on this problem.

Comment: You didn't clarify if you were talking about Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop or Server (they have different default as to default hardware stack), but have you tried using the other hardware stack?  (*mentioned as it's something easy; drivers being kernel modules are thus related to the kernel or kernel stack being used - given LTS releases come with two stack choices...*).

Comment: I've edited the question to mention that it is a 20.04 LTS Desktop